# URLs in the browser and language specific characters

Tags: php, url, encoding

Currently i have problems with my URLs having language specific characters such http://example.com/kjøretøy/biler/vw-golf and http://example.com//elektronikk/lydløs-stue-pc_i3.
When one copies the URL i get http://example.com//kj%C3%B8ret%C3%B8y/biler/vw-golf
and http://example.com//elektronikk/lydl%C3%B8s-stue-pc_i3.
I'm OSclass with SEF/Permalinks to generated search engine friendly URLs.
How can i show special chars like æ,ø,å shown as ae,oe and aa respectively in  URL of the browser?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Thx for that. But i forgot to mention that it's all done with Apache rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a little trick with htmlentities and preg_replace.
I usually use this home made function :

```
function url_sanitize($url) {
    $url = strtolower(htmlentities(str_replace(' ', '-', $url)));
    $url = preg_replace('#&([a-z])(?:acute|cedil|caron|circ|grave|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);#', '$1', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('#&([a-z]{2})(?:lig);#', '$1', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('#&[^;]+;#', '', $url);
    return $url;
}
```